# How to foreach list of arrs dynamically in php

Tags: php, arrays, list, loops, foreach

How can I put this array in foreach loop

```
Array (
    [title] => title0
    [des] => body0
    [0] => Array ( [title] => title1 [des] => body1 )
    [1] => Array ( [title] => title2 [des] => body2 )
    [2] => Array ( [title] => title3 [des] => body3 )
    [3] => Array ( [title] => title4 [des] => body4 )
    [4] => Array ( [title] => title5 [des] => body5 )
    [5] => Array ( [title] => title6 [des] => body6 )
    [6] => Array ( [title] => title7 [des] => body7 )
    [7] => Array ( [title] => title8 [des] => body8 )
    [8] => Array ( [title] => title9 [des] => body9 )
)
```

I tried

```
foreach($array as $a){
    echo $a->title;
}
```

but it didn't work out.

Error I got

```
ErrorException
Attempt to read property "title" on string
```

Comment: Your array has varying depths.  The first two elements `title` and `desc`  are scalar while all other instances of `title` and `desc` are nested in rows.  Looks like an XY problem where you have inappropriately built your array.  `->` is for accessing object properties.  You don't have an object and therefore, no properties.  You have an array which in some cases contains arrays. Please always present your PHP array data on Stack Overflow from `var_export()`. You can find my conditional nested foreach advice on the dupe target.

Comment: help me with the php code

Comment: ...I did already.  Help yourself to my free, pre-existing advice.

Comment: your explanation is not understandable at all

Comment: You know you have no solution you rush and close it, this is bad.

Comment: I know that I have offered the correct solution.  I have been generous in explaining the problem in my comment. I have even directed you to the exact answer on the duplicate page that will handle your data.  There is no possible way that you are going to make me feel guilty about appropriately closing this page as a duplicate.  If you are not a programmer or a programming enthusiast, then Stack Overflow is probably not the right place for -- you may wish to hire a programmer if you are unable to understand the very clear and basic advice being presented.

Comment: This solved my problem

```foreach ($curated as $key => $value) {

    $gg = json_decode($value);
    print_r($gg->title);
}```

Comment: Okay, that's great, but your question doesn't present any json strings at all.  There is no way that anyone could have known that you had json data.

Comment: I converted to json before decoding. @mickmackusa thanks anyway your explanation really helped